# Shared memory between threads on assembly level

Tags: multithreading, assembly, nasm, shared-memory

So i have program in C that creates threads using pthread library and calls function written in assembly.

My question is: 
How can I get shared memory between threads that run assembly code?

I know that i can pass pointer

```
typedef struct{
    int *value;
    } t_data;

static int global_value = 0;

int main(){
    t_data td;
    td.value = &global_value
    //creating threads in loop or something with id declared
    pthread_create(id, NULL, &assembly_foo, (void*)&td)
    assembly_foo((void*)&td)
    //joining threads
}
```

so at the assembly level both threads can increase value of global_value:

```
global assembly_foo

section .text

assembly_foo:
    mov rsi, [rdi]
    lock inc dword[rsi]
    ret
```

The thing is - i want to do something similiar, but without passing any argument. 
As far as I know registers and stack are distinct for each thread.
I don't need this value in C later, I just need some (compile-time constant) shared bytes to implement some kind of spinlock/mutex so I can synchronize threads.

Comment: Threads share all their entire virtual address space; static storage in .bss or .data is the easiest way, or you can pass a pointer as an arg to the thread's init function.

Comment: so if for example i have earlier declared
```
.bss
shared_data resb 4096
```
and have 50 threads running this function, it will take only 4kB and be shared between all 50 threads?

Comment: Yes, exactly like in C if you have multiple threads access the same global variable directly.  They literally compile to asm that just does that.

Comment: Every byte in memory that is accessible by a given thread is also accessible at the same address by every other thread in the same process.

Comment: @PeterCordes - caveat - for some operating systems, such as windows, there are some "per thread" variables, such as the seed value for rand(). These can be accessed using either fs or gs (i don't remember which), or can be mapped into the virtual address space.

Comment: @rcgldr While the base value for FS/GS changes for each thread, they still point to the same virtual address space that the other segment registers use.